# Не отправляется письмо по ajax запросу

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Содержание файла `index.php`:

```html
<form id="visa-form" method="post" action="mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ФИО</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_fullname" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Пол</label>
        <select name="user_gender" class="form-control">
            <option value="Мужской">Мужской</option>
            <option value="Женский">Женский</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Номер телефона</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_phone" class="form-control" pattern="\d*" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Эл. почта</label>
        <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Место работы</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_workplace" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <input id="send-visa-form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Содержание файла `main.js`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert("yup");
    $(function() {
      $('#visa-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: $form.attr('method'),
          url: $form.attr('action'),
          data: $form.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert(`success: ${$form.attr("method")} ${$form.attr("action")}`);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert(`success: ${$form.attr("method")} ${$form.attr("action")}`);
        });
        //отмена действия по умолчанию для кнопки submit
        e.preventDefault(); 
      });
    });
});
```

Содержание файла `mail.php`:

```php
<?php 
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$message = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
    return $string;
}
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

try 
{
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $message = '
        Name: ' . $_POST["user_fullname"] . '
        Gender: ' . $_POST['user_gender'] . '
        Phone: ' . $_POST["user_phone"] . '
        Email: ' . $_POST["user_email"] . '
        Workplace: ' . $_POST["user_workplace"] . '
        ';
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
        $mail->Port = '465';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'FromMail@mail.ru';
        $mail->Password = 'password';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->From = 'FromMail@mail.ru';
        $mail->FromName = 'FromName';
        $mail->AddAddress('MyMail@mail.ru', 'Name');
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
        $mail->Body = $message;
        if($mail->Send())
        {
            // success
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
        }
    }
} 
catch (Exception $error)
{
    echo 'Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

}
finally
{
    // header('location: index.php'); Убрал поскольку возвращал код 302
}
```

Делаю `ajax` запрос на отправку почты, отправка почты (скрипт `mail.php`) работает. Т. е. если отключить файл `mail.js` и отправить форму, то поля успешно отправляются и письмо приходит на почту. Но если отправить форму с `ajax`, то выполняется `success` (выводится сообщение об успешном отправлении запроса, **НО** письмо с данными полей не приходит. 
**Network**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Headers `mail.php`**

```
Request URL: http://ajaxtest/mail.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 22 May 2020 07:59:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=120, max=1000
Server: Apache
Accept: ***
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 308
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: ajaxtest
Origin: http://ajaxtest
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://ajaxtest/index.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.104
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
user_fullname: ***** ******* *******
user_gender: *****
user_phone: ***
user_email: ******
user_workplace: *****
```

Comment: но у вас даже в случае фэйла алертится success... Посмотрите в инструментах разработчика, что возвращает запрос.

Comment: так, файл после отправки запроса файл `mail.php` возвращал код `302`, потом я убрал назначение `header('location: index.php')` и теперь получение возвращает код `200`. Но, хех, тем не менее письмо не приходит

Comment: А что в теле ответа приходит?

Comment: @IvanDudarev `success: post mail.php` это выводится в алерте

Comment: В разделе Network тыкните на mail.php и посмотрите там, что ответил сервер.

Comment: @IvanDudarev дополнил вопрос

Comment: Это заголовки запроса. А нужен ответ.

Comment: @IvanDudarev так ведь `Response` показывает `This request has no response data available`

Comment: а без ajax запроса php скрипт работает корректно, письмо отправляется? в js коде добавьте метод  success и error и выведете в консоль ответы для обоих случаев: `success: function(data){  
        console.log(data);  
    }`. и для error

Comment: так же в php коде у вас в случае если $mail->send true, не выводится никакой ответ. начните тестировать со стороны php без использования ajax, может найдете ошибку

Comment: @МаксМаксимус в вопросе я отметил что php работает корректно, и письмо не приходит ТОЛЬКО когда запрос посылается через ajax

Comment: у вас в php стоит проверка `isset($_POST["submit"])`, а в приведенном вами скрине hraders от mail.php я не увидел, чтоб этот параметр передавался на сервер. Поэтому ваше условие и не выполняется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в php стоит проверка isset($_POST["submit"]), а в приведенном вами скрине hraders от mail.php я не увидел, чтоб этот параметр передавался на сервер. Поэтому ваше условие и не выполняется. Либо передавайте на сервер значение submit либо измените условие проверки, например, if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ), т.е. если к нам на mail.php кто-то стучится методом POST, проверяем что нам прислали и т.д. (пишем нашу дальнейшую логику)

Comment: Так же на стороне сервера желательно обязательно проверять полученные от клиента данные(проверить на пустоту, на валидность телефона, почты, длину имени пользователя). В зависимости от этого отдавать на клиент разные ответы (проверка пройдена или нет, письмо отправлено/не отправлено)

Comment: так же у вас есть функция clean_text() для замены спецсимволов, но  вы ее не используете, а передаете в body письма "сырые" данные из $_POST